# Registration form with new fields related

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

i am trying to add fields to my registration form with FosUserBundle.

Adding normal fields to the Userclass like "name", "age" e.g is easy to do:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // add your custom field
    $builder
        ->add('name')
    ;
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'acme_user_registration';
}
}
```

This is all working and the new fields are written to my database table.

But how do i add there a new FormType into the Registration type of the Fos Bundle, like:
A user can have an Address, which is related OneToMany.

I tried it with the following, by first creating the address class and giving him one user:

```
   /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="addresses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

And then by adding addresses to the User class:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $addresses;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // your own logic
    $this->addresses= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Adding the AddressType:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('state', 'text')
    ->add('city','text')
    ->add('zipcode', 'text')
    ->add('street', 'text');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' =>  'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Address',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'address';
}
}
```

to the RegistrationFormType works and the fields are displayed in the browser:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // add your custom field
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('addresses', new AddressType())
    ;
}
```

But when i try to submit the form with new data, i don't know how to say symfony that the address entered should be related to the User.
Im always getting the error:

"The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Address, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Address."

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to add a collection as a single field, when you give a "data_class" you're saying "here this is the form for this entity", but as the error says the system has to manage a collection of forms each one related to a single entity, you need to data transform them to something he can manage in a simple (or prebuilt) way (look for DataTransformers)

or you can use the [colletion](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) field type and pass them the address form type

-- edited after the comment --

no, sorry i've missed that, you need an entity form type because you state that a user has one address (and many user can be mapped to the same address, i.e. a family), so there's no need of a collection, though you're in the owning side persisting the user you don't have to worry, if you say cascade persist in your mapping schema for the ManyToOne relation, Doctrine will store the address for you (or use an existing one in case of a matching one)

btw i was fuzzed by your sentence "A user can have an Address, which is related OneToMany." that's misleading, a user can have an address, which is related to a ManyToOne relation (many user can have an address), the address is in a oneToMany relation with users (an address is own by many users)

Comment: Ok, so even if im just adding one address during the registration to a user, as there is the OneToMany relation I need to use the collection field type ? And if im using the collection type, the address will then be automatically mapped to the user, so in mysql there will be an entry in "address" relating to the new user ?
Regards

Comment: I thought that one user can have many addresses and one address can be mapped to one user. (OneToMany)
But what you are saying also sounds right..(ManyToOne) so would it be then a ManyToMany relation? I will have a look at the Entity type, thanks a lot!

Comment: Or would it be even a OneToOne relation when i just let the user enter one address during the registration process and no "optional" address ? i Would say that User(1) - Address (*) is the right way..

Comment: a OneToOne relation with nullable = true (actually the join column has the nullable attribute) will be what you're looking for then

Comment: Ok. The ManyToOne of you now makes the most sense to me, i thought about your family example. I think thats what i was looking for :-) I'll write here soon when i tried to implement the Entity method.

Comment: Im not at home atm, but i read the documentation of Entity.. and i don't get it so well. How am I adding the AddressType() to my RegistrationFormType and establish the connection between the address object and the User object ? 

I thought of something like that:

$builder->add('address', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Address',
    'property' => 'users',
));

(Using the Address OneToMany relation with users.)
It is a bit confusing due to the FOSUserBundle..